# flex scrolling module application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am working on a modular application. The problem is that scrolling doesn't work with datagrid and AdvancedDataGrid even in a non-modular application on FF and Chrome on Windows, works fine on IE. On mac, it works fine with FF 4.0 and chrome. Any ideas how to get it working on FF and chrome on windows?

Comment: Can you post the code?  Can't say I've had trouble with Windows, only with Macs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a larger problem with scrolling in general not working in FF and Chrome (and likely other webkit based browsers.  See my answer here:

[MouseWheel in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485187/mousewheel-in-chrome-y-firefox/5489123#5489123)