# Mouse wheel event is not firing in IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

Our company has a solution for graph visualization, made of Flash.

We bonded an event to mouse wheel move event on Flash.

It works in Chrome and IE9 compatibility mode, but not in IE9.

Maybe I can use jquery to do same thing, but I don't want any walkaround.

Did anybody get same symptom?

Comment: works for me on my project. Maybe you can give a try to such trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5489123/1517816

Comment: oh thanks. if you post it on 'answers', I'll pick it for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on my project.

Maybe you can give a try to such trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5489123/1517816

HIH
M.