# I'm having trouble with the AS3 MOUSE_WHEEL Mouse.Event in Chrome and IE

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have a swf with the wmode = window.
The event listener for MOUSE_WHEEL works fine when viewing in Firefox but when viewed in Chrome or IE the event never fires.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need some JS on the webpage to intercept the event and pass it manually to the SWF. This question/answer covers it (even if the wmode/browsers with issues are different, it's worth giving it a go):

[MouseWheel in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485187/mousewheel-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Hope this helps!